# One View with Runtime Changing ViewModels

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm doing a business UWP app where I have lots of data entry from various tables. While the data to fill out changes the basic layout of the view is always consistent. In my mind it should be easy to load the View and then just swap out the VM's during runtime?

I'm essentially trying to keep the same page updated the same way for multiple entry forms when all i need to do is change the view models and use template selectors?

I'm asking because I've never seen anyone do this before but to me that is one of the points of MVVM is that you can swap thing out easily. Anyone have any comments or experience about this?

Answer (score 1):

You can just change your `ViewModel` that bind the xaml UI to update the View. Here is a simple example to clarify it.

I have a `TestModel` class,

```
public class TestModel
{
    public string ShowText { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the XAML,

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <viewmodel:TestViewModel/>
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModelList}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ShowText}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

If you want to change the view data, you can just operate the `TestViewModel` to change the data to update the View content. In this sample, I use a `DispatcherTimer` to change the ViewModel,

This is the `ViewModel` class,

```
public TestViewModel()
{
    ViewModelList = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();

    ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is first test" });
    ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is second test" });
    ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is third test" });

    //Create a timer to update the data source.
    var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
    dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
    dispatcherTimer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
{
    ViewModelList.Add(new Models.TestModel() { ShowText = "this is the added item" });
}
```

If you want to update the View automatically by the property's changing in the `ViewModel` class, you maybe need to implement the [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) Interface. Here is the sample code of `ViewModel` class,

```
public class TestViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public TestViewModel()
    {
        ViewModelList = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is first test" });
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is second test" });
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is third test" });

        var dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    int i;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        i++;
        ViewModelList = new ObservableCollection<TestModel>();
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is first test" + ">>" + i });
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is second test" + ">>" + i });
        ViewModelList.Add(new TestModel { ShowText = "this is third test" + ">>" + i });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<TestModel> _ViewModelList;
    public ObservableCollection<TestModel> ViewModelList
    {
        get
        {
            return _ViewModelList;
        }
        set
        {
            _ViewModelList = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ViewModelList");
        }
    }
}
```

You can learn more from the [Data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/) topic and [{Binding} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/binding-markup-extension) document.

Comment: I already did this a different way but putting the viewmodels in a collection is a cool idea! didn't think of that. I just have the navigation menu changing the viewmodel directly in a XAML page i'm showing in a frame. then using datatemplateselectors to change out the data unique to the viewmodels.

Comment: @beatnikthedan Could you create a solution for your this question? It will provide a better idea for other developers include me. Thanks.